Showing the following wave equation solution vanishes for $||\vec{x}||>|t|$
For $(t,\vec{x}) \in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n$ we put
$$
f(t,\vec{x}) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} \int_{\vec{k}\in\mathbb{R}^n}
    e^{i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x} - ||\vec{k}||t)} d^n k  \,.
$$
Then $f(t,\vec{x})$ is a solution of the unit-wavespeed
wave equation
$(\partial_t^2 - \nabla_x^2) f=0$.
Furthermore, when $t=0$ we have $f(t=0,\vec{x}) = \delta^n(\vec{x})$.
Therefore, we view $f(t,\vec{x})$ as a wave that starts at $t=0$ as "concentrated at the origin", then for $t>0$ this wave "spreads out" according to the wave equation (in a way also depending on the "time derivative" $\partial_t f$ at $t=0$); but since our wave equation is for unit-speed waves, $f$ should spread out at a speed of at most 1, which should imply $f(t,\vec{x})=0$ for $||\vec{x}||>t>0$. (And by time-reversal symmetry, the same happens for $t<0$; so we expect $f(t,\vec{x})=0$ for $||\vec{x}||>|t|$, for any $t$.)

However, I wasn't able to prove the claim

$f(t,\vec{x})=0$ for $||\vec{x}||>|t|$

"directly"; would anyone have a suggestion for how this can be done? (Or, if my reasoning above is incorrect, could anyone help explain where it is flawed?)
